# Dynamic Stage name in EaselJS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, createjs, easeljs

I'm currently working on a site designed to display multiple canvases at the same time, without knowing which canvases it's going to display in advance (a PHP script creates the list).

The idea is to have multiple script files (one per canvas) be read by (typically) a single handler which will populate the individual stages.

```
stage = new createjs.Stage(context);
```

I'm stuck here. At the time I create a given stage, I know the name of the canvas I want to attach it to (for instance, stageA) and it's available in JavaScript in the variable named context. In this situation, I need to create an easeljs stage named stageA; the problem is I can't know in advance I won't need stageB instead of stageA so the created stage's name needs to be dynamic (equal to context). I tried something along the lines of

```
eval(context) = new createjs.Stage(context);
```

but it's not working as is.

(I also need to be able to operate on this dynamically named stage, ie be able to do

```
stageA.update();
```

for instance, without knowing stageA is called stageA but just based on context.)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bracket notation for global variables with either `windows["stageA"]` or if you know you are in global scope `this["stageA"]`

So if you have a context in global scope and you have a string with its variable name then you can access it via bracket notation like so

```
var stageA = // context of canvas
var stageName = "stageA"
var theStage = window[stageName];
```

Now `theStage` references `stageA`.

```
theStage.clearRect(0,0,100,100); 
// same as
stageA.clearRect(0,0,100,100);
```

All object attributes can be accessed via either **dot notation** ie `window.alert` or **braket notation** ie `window["alert"]`. As braket notation takes a string you can use a variable in its place.

Another example

```
   var myObj = {
       attributeA : 10,
   }
   console.log(myObj.attributeA); // output 10;
   console.log(myObj["attributeA"]); // output 10;
   var attributeName  = "attributeA";
   console.log(myObj[attributeName]); // output 10;
```

The global scope is called `window` but most people drop the window and directly reference the global scope. EG `window.alert` is the same as `alert` or `window.requestAnimationFrame` is the same as `requestAnimationFrame`

The global scope is also called `this` but you will need to know you are in global scope. If you are confident then `this["alert"]` or `window["alert"]` or `alert` or `window.alert` or `this.alert` are all the same reference if you are in global scope.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very helpful. Now stuck a little further down the road at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969195/targetting-multiple-stages-children-by-name-in-easeljs). (Was going to ask within the commentary, but it ended up taking too much space.)